# How to copy-item with folder structure?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

this is my code :

$path is an array who contains full files path I want to copy.

```
$path 

Y:\13000\00000001.TIF
Y:\14000\00000002.TIF
Y:\15000\00000004.TIF

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $path.count; $i++)
{ 
Copy-Item -Recurse -Path $path[$i] -Destination "D:\myfiles"
}
```

It works, but it copy me files directly at the root of `D:\myfiles` folder, I want to copy my files into them respective folder.. who already exists.

this is what I get :

```
D:\myfiles\00000001.TIF
D:\myfiles\00000002.TIF
D:\myfiles\00000003.TIF
```

And this is want I want :

```
D:\myfiles\13000\00000001.TIF
D:\myfiles\14000\00000002.TIF
D:\myfiles\15000\00000003.TIF
```

How to achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the destination parent folder already exists as you mentioned, then you can do this:

```
$paths = 'Y:\13000\00000001.TIF', 'Y:\14000\00000002.TIF', 'Y:\15000\00000004.TIF'

foreach ($item in Get-Item $paths)
{  
    Copy-Item -Path $item.FullName -Destination "D:\myfiles\$($item.Directory.Name)"
}
```

Note the use of the variable expansion, `$($item.Directory.Name)`, in the `-Destination` string to identify the parent folder.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i would do it, explanation in comments, hope it's understandable :)

This approach should be able to handle network paths, if you needed that functionality.

```
$path =
@(
    'Y:\13000\00000001.TIF'
    'Y:\14000\00000002.TIF'
    'Y:\15000\00000004.TIF'
)

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $path.count; $i++)
{
    # Change this for additional directories
    $sourceFolder = 'D:\myfiles'

    # Get the old path and split on a semi colon
    # Where-Object to filter out empty strings / null entries
    $sourceFile = $path[$i] -Split "\\" | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_}

    # Join the path we split to our destination
    # 1 is the 2nd item in the index (0 is the first)
    # $source.count - 2 will get the second last item in the index
    # (-2 because we're taking off the first and last)
    #
    #    [0]         [1]                [2]
    #    Y:    \    15000     \      00000004.TIF
    #
    # Once done, join all the parts back together with -Join '\'
    $destination = Join-Path -Path $sourceFolder -ChildPath ($sourceFile[1..($sourceFile.count - 2)] -Join "\")

    # Copy files to the destination we calculated
    # Don't need -Recurse if we're giving full paths but up to you
    Copy-Item -Recurse -Path $path[$i] -Destination $destination
}
```